# Помогите недопрограмисту разобраться в html

Tags: html, разметка

Решил я значит выучить html смотрел вики гайды но так и не понял как выровнять текст по вертикали для одного уровня с картинкой? vertical alighn работать не хочет внешние отступы внутри headera тоже не работают line height работает но в браузере (google chrome) все сбивается и в принципе все элементы сбиваются пишу в vs2017 до этого работал только с xaml и пишу по аналогии

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head runat="server">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <title>Veils</title>
    <link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <meta name="veils" content="comments" >
    <meta name="keywords" content="Veils" >
    <meta name="viewport" content="weight=device-width, initial-scale=1" >
    <link href="img/iconV.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon">
    <style type="text/css">
    #top {width: 1001px;}
    </style>
</head> 

<body>
       <header class="head">            
               <a class="name" href="#">
               <img src="img/logo.png" title="Veils" alt="#" width="130">                                    
               </a>
               <a class="name2" href="#">
                 Logo                     
               </a>
        </header>   
</body>
```

[image: Html код]

[image: Css файл]

Comment: html не является языком программирования. Вместо скриншотов вставьте текст, а еще лучше как фрагмент кода.

Comment: я знаю что это язык разметки но не знаю как им размечать хэх просто решил показать конструктор для большей понятности